# EdgePan Gesture not working when UINavigationController is inside container

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I need to place an `UINavigationController` (orange area) with some margin (in practise just 8px, here 50px) to outer screen, simplified like this:

[image: Viewcontroller with embedded <code>UINavigationController</code>]
Naturally the `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` does not work anymore - due to the gap between edge and controller.

Maybe a possible solution would be using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` instead and forwarding some events to the UINavigationConmtroller?

Anybody out there having an idea to archive this?

Thanks in advance!